# is it possible to make an inverted prediction with an nlsList object?

Tags: r, object, model, prediction

I have fitted an nlsList model with my data and now I need to estimate the value of "x" corresponding to a given "y" using my model.

I have tried with "invest" from investr package, but it works only with objects from class lm, glm, nls, or lme.

Comment: You should add some data and some code. estimating x from a given y can be straightforward or complicated depending on your model.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting to SO the question needs to provide a reproducible example for testing including input, code and expected output.  See the instructions at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page. I have done it for you this time in the Note at the end.

Create a function `pred` which predicts `Sepal.Width` given `Sepal.Length` and `Species`.  Then we can use `uniroot` as shown:

```
library(nlme)
# run code in Note

pred <- function(Sepal.Length, Species) {
  predict(fm, list(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length, Species = Species))
}
uniroot(function(x) pred(x, "virginica") - 3, c(-10, 10))
```

This gives the following which says that the `Sepal.Length` corresponding to a `Sepal.Width` of 3 and `Species` virginica is 6.7168.

```
$root
[1] 6.716803

$f.root
   virginica 
2.524802e-06 
attr(,"label")
[1] "Predicted values"

$iter
[1] 5

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

### Note

Reproducible example using built=in iris data set follows.  We assume that given Sepal.Width = 3 and Species = "virginica" that we want to find `Sepal.Length`.

```
library(nlme)
fm <- nlsList(Sepal.Width ~ a * exp(Sepal.Length*b) | Species, data = iris, 
  start = list(a = 0.5, b = 0.5))
```

Comment: Thanks! it helps me to find a way to solve my problem! I will include more information next time, it was my first one.